# How to pass property to root view controller while presenting UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, browser, uinavigationcontroller

I'm doing in-app browser to open links w-out using safari from any viewController in app.
This is a code for launching browser with link in AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)openExternalRef:(NSString *)ref
{
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   CSDBrowser* browser = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CSDBrowser"];
   browser.urlString = ref;
   browser.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   UINavigationController* navi = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CSDBrowserNavi"];

   [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:navi animated:YES completion:nil];
   [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:browser animated:YES];

}
```

i need to pass a variable "ref" to my viewcontroller, but i need to launch navigation controller first, any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. If you don't know how to access to your viewController describe your controllers hierarchy and `self.window.rootViewController`.

Comment: i need to access browser ViewController from any window of my app, but i need it with navigation bar. so, in order to have my navBar displayed, i need to launch a navigation controller first. this way i can't pass my property to browserVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
UINavigationController* navi = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CSDBrowserNavi"];

CSDBrowser* browser = [navi viewControllers][0];
browser.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

browser.urlString = ref;

[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:navi animated:YES completion:nil];
```